# health check fails without public ip in ec2 but works when public ip assigned

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Im creating auto scaling group and installing ngnix there. For some reason my target group has failed healtchecks, but if I assign public IP to my ec2 then healthcheck works. Maybe something with security groups, but I have no idea what could be wrong. Ec2 instances allow inbound from security group of load balancer on port 80.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet_1" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "eu-central-1a"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet_2" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.2.0/24"
  availability_zone = "eu-central-1b"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "ec2_sg" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  name        = "allow_tls"
  description = "Allow TLS inbound traffic and all outbound traffic"


  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.alb_sg.id]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "alb_sg" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "my_igw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
}

resource "aws_route" "internet_access" {
  route_table_id         = aws_vpc.my_vpc.main_route_table_id
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  gateway_id             = aws_internet_gateway.my_igw.id
}
```

```
resource "aws_lb" "my_alb" {
  name               = "my-alb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [var.alb_sg_id]
  subnets            = [var.subnet_1_id, var.subnet_2_id]

  tags = {
    Name = "my-alb"
  }
}


resource "aws_launch_template" "my_launch_template" {
  name_prefix   = "my-launch-template"
  image_id      = "ami-09042b2f6d07d164a"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  network_interfaces {
    security_groups = [var.ec2_sg_id]
  }
  user_data = "IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gKCiMgVXBkYXRlIHBhY2thZ2UgaW5kZXgKc3VkbyBhcHQgdXBkYXRlCgojIEluc3RhbGwgTmdpbngKc3VkbyBhcHQgaW5zdGFsbCAteSBuZ2lueAoKIyBTdGFydCBOZ2lueApzdWRvIHN5c3RlbWN0bCBzdGFydCBuZ2lueAoKIyBFbmFibGUgTmdpbnggdG8gc3RhcnQgb24gYm9vdApzdWRvIHN5c3RlbWN0bCBlbmFibGUgbmdpbngK"

  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"
    tags = {
      Name = "my-instance"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "my_autoscaling_group" {
  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.my_launch_template.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }

  min_size             = 2
  max_size             = 5
  desired_capacity     = 3
  vpc_zone_identifier  = [var.subnet_1_id, var.subnet_2_id]
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "my_target_group" {
  name        = "my-target-group"
  port        = 80
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  target_type = "instance"

  health_check {
    path                = "/"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    port                = "traffic-port"
    interval            = 30
    timeout             = 5
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
    matcher = "200-399"

  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_attachment" "example1" {
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.my_autoscaling_group.name
  lb_target_group_arn    = aws_lb_target_group.my_target_group.arn
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "application_listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.my_alb.arn
  port              = 80
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.my_target_group.arn
    type             = "forward"
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the instance doesn't start up correctly if it doesn't have a public IP address.  If you create an instance without a public IP, and you SSH into the instance to check the status of the web server running on it (whatever you have listening on port `80`), is the web server actually running? It looks like you are installing nginx as part of the user-data. I bet the install fails without a public IP, because it can't reach the Internet to download nginx.